# Any idea how to get a Jolt Spec for if-else condition

Tags: json, if-statement, jolt

I have the below Jolt and on the want to put the desc body in a **`"no"`** or **`without "no"`** depending upon the `delete` operation defined in `"yang:operation"`. Tried below Jolt, but looks like not hitting the condition defined in `"\\@desc"`:

Input JSON

```json
{
  "ABC": [
    {
      "@desc": {
        "yang:operation": "delete"
      },
      "desc": "attr1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Jolt Spec provided

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ABC": {
        "*": {
          "\\@desc": {
            "yang:operation": {
              "#delete": {
                "desc": "no.desc.\\$\\.DESC.\\.DESC"
              },
              "*": {
                "desc": "desc.\\$\\.DESC.\\.DESC"
              }
            }
          },
          "desc": "desc.\\$\\.DESC.\\.DESC"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Expected Output

```json
{
  "no" : {
    "desc" : {
      "$.DESC" : {
        ".DESC" : "attr1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you're so close to the solution, just innermost `desc` keys should be qualified with `#` wildcard, eg. `#desc`; but not the top level `delete` key.

As a result you can retry with the following spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ABC": {
        "*": {
          "\\@desc": {
            "yang:operation": {
              "delete": {
                "#desc": "no.desc.\\$\\.DESC.\\.DESC"
              },
              "*": {
                "#desc": "desc.\\$\\.DESC.\\.DESC"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and the outer(the second) `"desc": "desc.\\$\\.DESC.\\.DESC"` seems to have no sense, just remove it.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros Özhan for the response, I tried the above Jolt, but it causing the loss of value "attr1". I want to read that value inside the "no" and assign it to "desc"

Comment: Below Jolt Specs is working:

[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ABC": {
        "*": {
          "\\@desc": {
            "yang:operation": {
              "delete": {
                "@(3,desc)": "no.desc"
              },
              "*": {
                "@(3,desc)": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Comment: Hi @Lakhan , you're welcome. Your last spec results `{
  "no" : {
    "desc" : "attr1"
  }
}` but you have mentioned that you expect to get `{
  "no" : {
    "desc" : {
      "$.DESC" : {
        ".DESC" : "desc"
      }
    }
  }
}` ... Btw, don't you want to have `{
  "desc" : {
    "$.DESC" : {
      ".DESC" : "desc"
    }
  }
}` for `yang:operation` with value different than `delete` ?

Comment: Yes, removed the .DESC as it was just getting nested as you mentioned. Was trying to read the value from "desc" and assign in case op is delete. 
Thanks for helping out.